# Generating a key for a quantile scale used for a choropleth map d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to generate a key for a quantile scale used to generate a choropleth map. The quantile scale has a range of 11 colours, but I can only seem to generate a key for 10 of the 11 colours.

Here's the code for the quantile scale:

```
  const educMin = d3.min(mapData.objects.counties.geometries, d => d.properties.bachelorsOrHigher);
  const educMax = d3.max(mapData.objects.counties.geometries, d => d.properties.bachelorsOrHigher);
  const colourScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
                        .domain([educMin, educMax])
                   .range(['#fff5eb','#fee8d3','#fdd8b3','#fdc28c','#fda762','#fb8d3d','#f2701d','#e25609','#c44103','#9f3303','#7f2704']);
```

And here's the code for the legend:

```
 const legendBars = colourScale.quantiles()

 const legend = map.append('g')
                   .attr('id', 'legend')
                   .attr('transform', 'translate(495, 550)');
  
  legend.selectAll('rect')
        .data(legendBars)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
          return colourScale(d)
         })
        .attr('x', (d, i) => 20 * i)
        .attr('width', 20)
        .attr('height', 20);
```

This generates only 10 of the 11 colours specified in the quantile scale:

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMSVr.jpg)]

Link to full codepen here: (https://codepen.io/luke-worley/pen/YzvXMjM)

Could anyone explain how to generate a legend with all 11 colours?

Answer (score 1):

That number of colours (ten) is quite expected: your `colorScales.quantiles()` will simply return your range array (which has eleven elements) with one value less. The docs  about [`quantiles()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#quantile_quantiles) explain how it works:

> Returns the quantile thresholds. If the range contains n discrete values, the returned array will contain n - 1 thresholds.

That said, there's something not directly related to your question but very important: this is **not** the correct way to use a quantile scale: you have to pass the whole data array, that is, the `domain` is a population of values, not only the minimum and maximum. So, instead of:

```
domain([educMin, educMax])
```

It should be:

```
domain([mapData.objects.counties.geometries].map(d => d.properties.bachelorsOrHigher))
```

---

Edit: answering a comment, here's how your map looks like with the correct domain:

```js
fetch('https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/choropleth_map/counties.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const mapData = data;

    return fetch('https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/choropleth_map/for_user_education.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const educationData = data;

        const mapDataEducationAdded = mapData.objects.counties.geometries.forEach((x => {
          x.properties = educationData.find(({
            fips
          }) => fips === x.id);
        }));

        const colourScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
          .domain(mapData.objects.counties.geometries.map(d => d.properties.bachelorsOrHigher))
          .range(['#fff5eb', '#fee8d3', '#fdd8b3', '#fdc28c', '#fda762', '#fb8d3d', '#f2701d', '#e25609', '#c44103', '#9f3303', '#7f2704']);

        const toolTip = d3.selectAll('div#chart-container')
          .data(mapData.objects.counties.geometries)
          .enter()
          .append('div')
          .style('visibility', 'hidden')
          .style('position', 'absolute')
          .style('background-color', '#e6ffff')
          .style('white-space', 'pre')
          .style('padding', '10px')
          .style('text-align', 'center')
          .style('opacity', '0.8')
          .attr('id', 'tooltip');

        const toolTipMouseOver = (event, d) => {
          toolTip.text(`State: ${d.properties.state}
    County: ${d.properties.area_name}
    Bachelor's degree: ${d.properties.bachelorsOrHigher}%`);
          toolTip.style('top', (event.pageY) + 'px')
            .style('left', (event.pageX) + 'px')
            .attr('data-education', d.properties.bachelorsOrHigher);
          return toolTip.style('visibility', 'visible')

        }

        const toolTipMouseOut = (event, d) => {
          return toolTip.style('visibility', 'hidden');
        }

        const map = d3.select('div#chart-container')
          .append('svg')
          .attr('viewBox', '0 0 960 600')
          .attr('id', 'chart');

        const path = d3.geoPath();

        map.selectAll('path')
          .data(topojson.feature(mapData, mapData.objects.counties).features)
          .enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', path)
          .attr('fill', d => colourScale(d.properties.bachelorsOrHigher))
          .attr('class', 'county')
          .attr('data-fips', d => d.properties.fips)
          .attr('data-education', d => d.properties.bachelorsOrHigher)
          .on('mouseover', toolTipMouseOver)
          .on('mouseout', toolTipMouseOut);

        map.selectAll(null)
          .data(topojson.feature(mapData, mapData.objects.states).features)
          .enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', path)
          .attr('class', 'state')
          .attr('stroke', '#cccccc')
          .attr('stroke-width', '0.5px')
          .attr('fill', 'none');


      });
  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#chart-container-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#chart-container {
  width: 100%;
}

#chart {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 38vw;
}

#title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#description {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#tooltip {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.8;
}


/* Opacity doesn't work? */
```

```html
<h3 id=t itle>US adult educational attainment (2010-2014)</h1>
<h4 id=d escription>Proportion of adults aged ≥25 years with a bachelor degree or higher</h2>
<div id='chart-container-container'>
  <div id='chart-container'></div>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a reason why quantiles() returns n - 1 thresholds? Is there a way of returning the full 11? If not, should I be approaching generating the legend in a different way?

I also amended the domain as you suggested but I got the error:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bachelorsOrHigher')

Comment: `quantiles()` returns the thresholds, you want them just to set the text of the legend (the values). For generating the squares just use the array itself, you already have it, or just `scale.range()`.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much, I now have a legend of the full set of colours. I'm still not sure how to correctly pass the entire dataset to the quantile scale domain rather than just the minimum and maximum...it seems to populate the map ok, but is this not correct?

Comment: @LukeWorley have a look at the edit.

Comment: Ah, I think I was including the [] around the scaleQuantile domain. However, when passing the full dataset to the scaleQuantile domain, it changes the scaleQuantile array to:
[11.1, 12.9, 14.2, 15.7, 17.2, 18.6, 20.4, 22.9, 26.8, 32.8]
Which considering the minimum value in the dataset is 2.6 and the maximum is 75.1, I don't understand how this can be correct?

Passing the minimum and maximum values of the dataset generates an array that is evenly distributed between the minimum and maximum values:
[9.2, 15.8, 22.4, 29.0, 35.6, 42.1, 48.7, 55.3, 62.0, 69.0]
Any insight appreciated!